# Have element show when .onclick and when the element has focus from tab

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a search button on my page http://rockingh.nextmp.net/

```
            <div class="menu-search-button" tabindex="0" ></div>
             <p>
             <input class="menu-search-field type" type="text" name="keywords" placeholder="Type keyword and hit enter" id="keywords" value="" size="18" maxlength="100" >
            </p>
```

Has this css:

```
/* 3.1 - Navigation Search */
.menu-search-button {
background: url(../images/search_icon.png),url(../images/dot_border_v.png);
background-position: center -18px, top left;
background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-y;
background-color: #fff;
width: 80px;
height: 53px;
position: absolute;
right: 1px;
top: 1px;
z-index: 999;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.menu-search-button:hover {
background: url(../images/search_icon.png),url(../images/dot_border_v.png);
background-position: center -106px, top left;
background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-y;
background-color: #fff;
cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-search-form {
float: right;
}

.menu-search-field {
background: url(../images/dot_border_v.png) top left repeat-y #f8f8f8 !important;
width: 0%;
height: 52px;
border: none !important;
float: right;
padding: 1px 0px;
color: #b0b0b0;
font-size: 12px;
opacity: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 1px;
right: 0;
-webkit-appearance: none;
border-radius: 0;
}

.menu-search-focus {
width: 280px;
padding: 1px 0 0 10px;
opacity: 10;
}
```

It is run with JQuery:

```
 // Search Button Toggle    
jQuery(".menu-search-button").click(function() {
    jQuery(".menu-search-field").toggleClass("menu-search-focus", 200);
});
```

I am trying to make sure it is accessible. I have added the tabindex and it will show focus. The actual input will get focus also although you can't see it.
How can I make the input show up when it has focus, or even tell the menu-search-field to show up with a keyboard action also?

I have searched and it may be just my bad JQuery skills why I am not able to get this to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery will let you register a listener for the `focus` event using its [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function, just like you can for click events or any other events:

```
$(".menu-search-field").on("focus", function(event) {
  console.log("search field has received focus");
  // show search field here...
});
```

and you already know how to show the search field when an event is fired, since you're already doing that in your search button's click handler ( `jQuery(".menu-search-field").toggleClass("menu-search-focus", 200);` ).

so put them together and see what happens.

Comment: glad to hear it!  you also might want to check out the `blur` event, which fires when an element loses focus, in case you want to hide your search box again.

Comment: Will do! Thanks again!